# Tracking down a getChildHtml template file

Tags: product, template, html

I have been asked to make a seemingly simple change to a magento product page but I am having trouble tracking down the file.

The file *template/catalog/product/view.phtml* contains the line

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data')
```

I want to change the child html (or at least see it to find out if it is the file I'm after) but I can't find where it's coming from.

I have looked at the catalog.xml file and it contains the following block:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />
```

Should it not have a *template="something.phtml"* attribute to tell me where to go?

It displays (I think) a table with tabs for "Product Description", "Additional Information" and "Product's Reviews".

Thanks

Comment: http://www.pauldonnelly.net/magento-turning-on-template-path-hints/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often block will have default templates set in the block. In your example this is the case.

If you look in the file `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Additional` you will see the setting of the template.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/additional.phtml');
}
```

A great way of finding these template is by setting template hints via the admin.